# Eclipse Maven Project: Is it possible to use one version of JDK for project and another version of JDK for tests?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber

I heard that it is possible to use 2 different version of JDK in Eclipse (Oxygen) but I cannot figure out how.

I am trying to use JDK 1.8 for project source code, but JDK 11 for Cucumber tests.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to update your Eclipse first.

Comment: we cannot do that, it is governed by the company policy and we have to stay on that version.  but that is other topic, I dont want to open discussion about that.  Thank you

Comment: I am not sure but I guess it is better to stay with Java 8 until you are able to update Eclipse.